# adding text after subtotal price in mail template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know how to add text after the price on the site but it doesn't work for mail templates. I also tried in woocomerce settings but it doesn't work for mail.

this is for site:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' incl tax';
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

How can I target the mail template price?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use `woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display` filter.

Kindly check below code this will work for you.

```
  // define the woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display callback 
    function filter_woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display( $subtotal, $compound, $instance ) { 

        $subtotal .= ' incl tax'; // add your text here   

        return $subtotal; 
    }; 

    // add the filter 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display', 'filter_woocommerce_order_subtotal_to_display', 10, 3 );
```